# How to capitalize variable in eclipse template

Tags: eclipse

This is the question: I want to do a template for a header files in eclipse. So I use this syntax:

```
 #ifndef __${file_base}_INTERFACE__
```

My header files names need to be lowercase. But, into the definition guard it must appear uppercase. For example my header file is named **header.h**. Then in my template I get `__header_INTERFACE__`. Although I want this `__HEADER_INTERFACE__`.

So how to make the variable `${file_base}` to appear uppercase? Thank you!